# выполнение файла в mysql

Tags: mysql

изучаю mysql и php по книге. дошел до момента что надо из файла с расширением .sql вставить в таблицу  mysql. там написано что надо выполнить команду `mysql -h name_host -u name_user -D name_db -p < name_file.sql`. 
и вот непонятно куда надо вставить эту команду. если через терминал, то выдает ошибку "error 1045(280000): access denied for user", но для пользователя, который создан у меня на компьютере, а не в базе mysql. если создать пользователя с таким же именем, то выдает такую же ошибку.
OS macos high sierra

Answer (score 1):

оказывается надо просто прописать source "путь к файлу .sql". ну для тех кому будет нужно и наткнется на этот пост